# Tangent of a curve

Tags: geometry

Consider the curve $x=1$ in $xy$ plane. I want to know whether tangent 
at any point on this curve exist which is $x=1$, or tangent does not exist.

Comment: I might have misunderstood you, but tangent to a constant is that constant itself.

Comment: A tangent to a straight line is always the line itself. It exists, and it's the easiest possible!

Comment: Intuitively, the tangent line at a point on a curve is the line that the curve "looks like" when you zoom-in really, really, *RREEAALLLLYY* closely on the point. (If the curve doesn't look like a line up-close, then there's no tangent.) Now, no matter how closely you zoom-in on any line, the line it looks like is the line itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a line is tangent to a curve at a point if it passes through the point and has the same slope as the curve at that point. Notice that I didn't define *slope*. Clearly, $x=1$ is not a function, so it wouldn't be appropriate to define *slope* as $\displaystyle\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. Lets just say that the slope is vertical. According to this interpretation the tangent line for $x=1$ is $x=1$